# sending multiple goals to navigation stack

Tags: ros, navigation, multiple

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I want to send multiple goals to the navigation stack, that the robot should pass successively. I want to use a node similar to the node from this tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals. How can I use this node to send multiple goals?

Thank you in advance.

Update:

That is the code I am trying to use, but I am not sure what should be in the execute_cb-part:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import roslib
import rospy
import smach
import smach_ros
import actionlib

from move_base_msgs.msg import MoveBaseAction, MoveBaseGoal

# Create a action server
class WPServer:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self._sas = SimpleActionServer(name,
                Waypoints,
                execute_cb=self.execute_cb)

    def execute_cb(self, msg):
        if msg.goal == 0:
            self._sas.set_succeeded()
        elif msg.goal == 1:
            self._sas.set_aborted()
        elif msg.goal == 2:
            self._sas.set_preempted()

def main():
    rospy.init_node('waypoint_machine')

    # Create a SMACH state machine
    sm = smach.StateMachine(outcomes=['succeeded','aborted','preempted'])

    # Open the container
    with sm:
        # Add states to the container

    wp1 = MoveBaseGoal()
    wp1.target_pose.header.frame_id = '/map'
    wp1.target_pose.pose.position.x = 13
    wp1.target_pose.pose.position.y = 0
    wp1.target_pose.pose.orientation.w = 1.0
    StateMachine.add('Waypoint1',
                      SimpleActionState('WPServer',
                                        Waypoints,
                                        goal=wp1),
                      transitions={'succeeded':'Waypoint2'})

    wp2 = MoveBaseGoal()
    wp2.target_pose.header.frame_id = '/map'
    wp2.target_pose.pose.position.x = 18
    wp2.target_pose.pose.position.y = 0
    wp2.target_pose.pose.orientation.z = 0.70710678118
    wp2.target_pose.pose.orientation.w = 0.70710678118
    StateMachine.add('Waypoint2',
                      SimpleActionState('WPServer',
                                        Waypoints,
                                        goal=wp2),
                      transitions={'succeeded':'Waypoint3'})

    # Execute SMACH plan
    outcome = sm.execute()

    rospy.signal_shutdown('All done.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244175/sending-multiple-goals-to-navigation-stack/) by [gleb](https://answers.ros.org/users/27760/gleb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-09-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-09-22**:
Your code should implement an action *client*, not a server. Then your client will send goals to the `move_base` action server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In brief, you can write a custom node that instantiates a simple action server which sends a sequence of `MoveBaseActionGoal`s to `move_base`

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2016-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"I want to send multiple goals to the navigation stack, that the robot should pass **successively**"

I'm not really sure what you want to do ultimately, but you might want to use [smach](http://wiki.ros.org/smach) .
It is a state machine package in ROS.

Quoting from the page:

> When should I use SMACH?
>
> SMACH is useful when you want a robot
> to execute some complex plan, where
> all possible states and state
> transitions can be described
> explicitly. This basically takes the
> hacking out of hacking together
> different modules to make systems like
> mobile robotic manipulators do
> interesting things.

You can also control the goal/behavior of the robot depending on the result of the previous goal.

Check out the [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/smach/Tutorials)

------.

Here is an example from "Programming Robots with ROS" book:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
import actionlib
from smach import State,StateMachine
from move_base_msgs.msg import MoveBaseAction, MoveBaseGoal

waypoints = [
    ['one', (2.1, 2.2), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)],
    ['two', (6.5, 4.43), (0.0, 0.0, -0.984047240305, 0.177907360295)]
]

class Waypoint(State):
    def __init__(self, position, orientation):
        State.__init__(self, outcomes=['success'])

        # Get an action client
        self.client = actionlib.SimpleActionClient('move_base', MoveBaseAction)
        self.client.wait_for_server()

        # Define the goal
        self.goal = MoveBaseGoal()
        self.goal.target_pose.header.frame_id = 'map'
        self.goal.target_pose.pose.position.x = position[0]
        self.goal.target_pose.pose.position.y = position[1]
        self.goal.target_pose.pose.position.z = 0.0
        self.goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.x = orientation[0]
        self.goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.y = orientation[1]
        self.goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.z = orientation[2]
        self.goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.w = orientation[3]

    def execute(self, userdata):
        self.client.send_goal(self.goal)
        self.client.wait_for_result()
        return 'success'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('patrol')

    patrol = StateMachine('success')
    with patrol:
        for i,w in enumerate(waypoints):
            StateMachine.add(w[0],
                             Waypoint(w[1], w[2]),
                             transitions={'success':waypoints[(i + 1) % \
                             len(waypoints)][0]})

    patrol.execute()
```

---

Originally posted by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) with karma: 582 on 2016-09-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gleb](https://answers.ros.org/users/27760/gleb/) on 2016-09-22**:
Thank you for your answer, I think I can make it work with SMACH, but I am new to programming and not sure about my code, could you please check my code and help me fix it? I am gonna update my question with my code.

**Comment by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on 2016-09-22**:
@gleb You need to make actionclient, and send goal to the actionserver in this case move_base.
You don't need callback function, cause you are the one who'll be sending goals.  The move_base will have the callback function which actually handles the goal and move the robot to the goal location.

**Comment by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on 2016-09-22**:
@gleb I edited my answer with a code example. You can refer to it

**Comment by [gleb](https://answers.ros.org/users/27760/gleb/) on 2016-10-05**:
@alienmon thank you very much for your help, this code works for me! I want to integrate following line:

```
if self.client.get_state() == actionlib.SimpleClientGoalState.SUCCESS:
    return 'succeded'
else:
    return 'aborted'
```

**Comment by [gleb](https://answers.ros.org/users/27760/gleb/) on 2016-10-05**:
but I get this error : AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SimpleClientGoalState'!
Do you have an idea how to implement it right?

**Comment by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on 2016-10-05**:
The error is pretty clear actionlib doesn't have SimpleClientGoalState........................

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! Hoping it can be helpful to someone, I have wrote two posts about sending goals to the navigation stack with a Python node (with example code):

- Sending a single goal (equivalent to the C++ tutorial), [here](https://github.com/HotBlackRobotics/hotblackrobotics.github.io/blob/master/en/blog/_posts/2018-01-29-action-client-py.md).
- Sending a sequence of goals (complete of simulation with a turtlebot robot), [here](https://github.com/HotBlackRobotics/hotblackrobotics.github.io/blob/master/en/blog/_posts/2018-01-29-seq-goals-py.md).

Cheers!

---

Originally posted by [fiorellasibona](https://answers.ros.org/users/33559/fiorellasibona/) with karma: 131 on 2018-05-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-05-26**:
Can you please update your answer with more information including code examples that way it will be self-contained? If those pages move or disappear then this answer will be useless.

**Comment by [fiorellasibona](https://answers.ros.org/users/33559/fiorellasibona/) on 2019-03-04**:
Hi @jayess, I have updated my answer, thank you!

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-03-04**:
@fiorellasibona sorry for the confusion, but I meant putting the examples *in the answer*. The reason is is to keep answers self-contained because files/pages can and do disappear from other sites making the answers not helpful

**Comment by [amjack](https://answers.ros.org/users/57146/amjack/) on 2022-09-23**:
This worked for me on Noetic, Thanks.